# Can Anyone Explain This Ghostscript Error Message?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, converters, ghostscript, postscript

I am grabbing a thumbnail from each pdf in a directory.

```
$ convert problem.pdf problem.png
```

I have a problem PDF that causes the following error:

```
Error: /undefined in --run--
Operand stack:
   --dict:1/1(L)--   Nums
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1894   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:109/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:292/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:25/32(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 9.07: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

**Can anyone explain this error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally it means 'something went wrong'. Unless you are expert in disassembling PostScript and PDF that's about all you can say from that.

However, that looks very much like a bug which was fixed some time ago, you don't say which version of Ghostscript you are using but I can see you are using 9.07, the current version is 9.10, I would suggest you upgrade.